# Do I have malware or viruses?

Tags: mac, security, privacy, malware, virus

I have been having problems with my Mac for over a year now. I thought I had fixed this issue... for all that my limited computer knowledge would let me anyway, but it is back and seemingly different and worse this time.

I first found logs with all of my personal details late last year after I had noticed that iTunes seemed to be reopening at start up when it wasn't supposed to. I had lost permissions to look at some files, and then one night while I was sitting at my computer I heard the click of it taking a photo and knew I hadn't done it.

I have had to have my bank card re-issued 3 times this year as someone (apparently the bank can't trace this) was continually trying to take small amounts of money from my bank account. We presumed they gained my account numbers from my computer, but I have factory reset my computer 4 times. Apple have talked me through this but have never given me a reason why or even what is going on, instead usually challenging me by asking me what I am reading in my logs that makes me think there is a problem, and denying any possibility of there being malware or a virus on my computer.

One instance it took 2 full days for my computer to go through the reset process. And now I seem to have more problems, I have lost many permissions again, many of my logs are empty, it jumps between screens (Safari - Finder etc) by itself. I installed Dr Safety and Dr Cleaner from the App Store which both picked up a malware program on the first run but haven't again since. I also installed Anti-Virus Plus Security which is provided by Telstra, my service provider,  which did the same thing.

I can no longer take screenshots nor use the Spotlight search. I will attach here the console log I saved from this morning. I had turned the WiFi off at approx 3am, and at 5.23am I covered the camera with a sticker.

As I stated I really don't know what I am reading in these logs and hopefully I am being paranoid or something!?!

Please can someone help me work this out or let me know how I can fix it. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: of course you have them.